# Convert Resource array to File ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream, comparator

I am trying to read files from resource directory on a spring application.

```
private File[] sortResources(Resource[] resources) {
    assert resources != null;

    File[] files = Arrays.stream(resources).sorted()
            .filter(Resource::exists).filter(Resource::isFile).map(res -> {
                try {
                    return res.getFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            }
    ).toArray(File[]::new);

    for (File f : files) {
        System.out.println( f.getAbsolutePath() );
    }
    return files;
}
```

Using as follows:

```
// Read all directories inside dbdata/mongo/ directory.
Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("classpath:dbdata/mongo/*");
List<File> files = sortResources(Resource[] resources);
```

The problem is on `sortResources` function. I want to sort and convert the Resources objects to Files objects.

I can't get `.toArray()` to work, since I get the following error:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.ClassCastException' exception.

class org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I also tried `.collect(Collectors.toList())` but I get the same error.

Can someone help me on that?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(resources).sorted()` requires some logic on which criteria to sort. You can either pass a `Comparator` to `sorted` or the stream you want to sort has to contain elements that implement `Comparable`. The latter is not the case here, hence the Exception.

Comment: Sure you're not getting that from the `sorted()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource` obviously does not implement the `Comparable<T>` interface, so your call to `sorted` throws an Exception.

You could either pass a `Comparator` to `sorted`, but it would be easier to simply move the call to `sorted` *after* the `map` operation, since `java.io.File` does implement `Comparable`.

Comment: You are right! moving sorted to after the map did the trick. Thanks for our help!

Answer (score 1):

As @f1sh has already said the class `FileSystemResource` is not a subtype of `Comparable`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html

To sort your files, you need to provide a `Comparator` instance to the `sorted()` operation. Besides, since `sorted()` is a **stateful** intermediate operation, it would be better to place it after `filter()` in order to reduce the elements to sort. In fact, a stateful operation like `sorted()` needs all the elements of the previous operation to produce a result. Its drawback is quite visible under parallel computation as pipelines containing stateful intermediate operations may require multiple passes on the data or may need to buffer significant data.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Here is the updated version of your code:

```
private File[] sortResources(Resource[] resources) {
    assert resources != null;
    File[] vetRes = new File[0];
    return Arrays.stream(resources)
            .filter(r -> r.exists() && r.isFile())
            .map(r -> {
                try {
                    return r.getFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            })
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::getAbsolutePath))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(vetRes);
}
```

Comment: awesome complement. thanks a lot for your help!